# Callback when Google Maps Controls Elements are Loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I found other stack overflow questions suggesting that using the 'idle' event is the way to trigger a callback when a google map is completely loaded.  But in my case, I want to run some code to inject some text into an element in the map's UI, but I find that 'idle' fires before these elements are created.

To be explicit, I attach a initialize function to the window's load method:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Inside initialize, I create some UI elements and attach them to the map:

```
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-div"), mapOptions);
  ...
  // set up the controls div 
  var controlsDiv = document.createElement('div');
  controlsDiv.id="cd";
  controlSetup(controlsDiv);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(controlsDiv);
}
```

Okay, but then what I want to do is run a function once this is all ready.  In my case, I'm going to insert further text into the controls divs so I need those to be there.

I've tried this as the last line of the initialize method:

```
google.maps.events.addListenerOnce(map,'idle',emitText);
```

However, the emitText has a line which tries to getElementById("cd") (the controlsDiv on the map) but I get that it is null because the emitText has fired before the controlsDiv has actually finished loading.

The question, then, is how to detect the full loading of the map, including any UI divs.  My testing suggests that the 'idle' event is firing before the UI elements are loaded and accessible in the DOM.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: My temporary solution was just to put method that polls for existence before going ahead.  So now, in the last line of initalize, I call initialEmitText  instead of emitText.  The initialEmitText checks for null on the relevent element and sets a timeout to keep checking if they are null, if they aren't, it calls emitText.  I don't think this is super-elegant, but it works.  I'll leave the question open in case someone knows a better solution.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Wow, this was 3 years ago!  I'm pretty sure I ended up just sticking with the polling solution I described in the comment above.

Comment: thank you. this solution still works :)

Answer (score 2):

simply access `controlsDiv` instead of `getElementById("cd")`, it doesn't matter if the div has already been added to the document.

Comment: So, this should work if controlsDiv is a global variable.  It isn't so I need some way to access this object from a completely different method.  I ended up doing something like a workaround: I just do a 200 millisecond calback and loop until the getElementById doesn't return null, then I go ahead and format the text inside it.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I was trying to get the element by $("#<id>"), instead, I founded it using $(controlsDiv).find("#<id").

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when i want run jquery plugin in side Element after add to #map. So i solved with call back google map full load:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(g, 'idle', () => {
        setTimeout(function() {
         //do smt
        }, 1)
    });
```